# Subfields of irreducible polynomial fields with known dimensions

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let's say we have an irreducible polynomial, $h(x) = x^4 + x + 1 \in \Bbb F_2[x]$, and that L is a field equal to $\Bbb F_2 [x]/(h(x))$. How would I go about finding a subfield K such that $[L : K] = 2$? And how would I prove that the multiplicative group $K^*$ is cyclic?

All I've gotten so far is that $K$ will have four elements, although I think the set ($x^3, x^2, x, 1$) is too simple to be the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$? What do you mean by your "quotient field"? Is it simply division, or do you want the polynomial to generate a normal group to make sense out of your notation?

Comment: $F_2[x]$ refers to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, or polynomials with coefficients 0 or 1.

Comment: I believe the notation $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is more widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints/steps/suggestions/observations.

- You know that $L$ has sixteen elements. Therefore $K$ should have four. Therefore $K^*$ has three. What do you know about groups of three elements?
- $L^*$ has fifteen elements, so by Lagrange's theorem all $z\in L^*$ satisfy the equation $z^{15}=1.$ Similarly if $w\in K^*$ it is a solution of $w^3=1$. Can you show that all the solutions $y$ of $y^3=1$ are in $K^*$? Hint: How many solutions (at most) to a cubic equation in a field.
- Assuming that you can do the previous bullet, and given that $z^{15}=1$, for which exponents $m$ can you tell that $(z^m)^3=1$?
- After you have found the correct $m$ in the previous bullet, apply it to $z=x+\langle h(x)\rangle\in L$. Remember that the subfield $K$ has to be closed under addition and multiplication.
- Have you found all the four elements of $K$, and checked that it is a subfield? Time to mark this one as solved! You can also check/verify your solution to [my solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591253/discrete-logarithm-tables-for-the-fields-bbbf-8-and-bbbf-16). You are welcome to read through it all, but only the first paragraph afte the last horizontal line is relevant to this problem.